Tox with pyspark
We implemented unit tests for the Pyspark scenarios. But as tox creates the runtime environment and installs the required packages, every time I run tox, it has to install pyspark which takes around 3 minutes everytime. So how can I avoid this long package installation runtime so that my test stage in CI/CD pipeline will be executed faster?
Is there any other alternative for this? I did my due diligence but couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

Which CI/CD system are you using?
Many CI/CD systems (like GitHub Actions, GitLab CI, CircleCI, etc.) provide caching mechanisms to store and reuse dependencies between runs. By caching the PySpark installation, you can significantly reduce the setup time.
Checkout Github actions caching - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

you can also use pre-built docker Images, if your CI/CD system supports Docker, you can use pre-built Docker images that already include PySpark. This avoids the need to install PySpark every time the pipeline runs.

You can install Spark (bundled with PySpark) and add a .pth file to each of the Python installs' site-packages directories that references the python directory of the Spark install. I've done that with some success, but different Python versions are compatible with different Spark versions so you'll need multiple depending on your tox environments.

cool understood.
